# How can I create a Java "Screen Share" application?

Tags: java, screenshot, screen-capture

I've currently got a semi- working screenshare application, which does the following:

**Client**:

Capture the users Screen using a `Robot`

Detects which pixels have changed since the last screenshot

Sends the difference image through a compression stream

**Server**:

Decompresses the difference image

Overlays the image over the users last screen

---

Now, this works, but it's incredibly slow. It takes 200ms to process a 1920x1080 screen.

What other techniques could I use to make this more efficient? Also is there any way I could just encode multiple images into a .h264 stream or something similar? Are there any useful libraries that can compare the two images faster? Possibly on the GPU instead of the CPU?

Comment: Have you identified the bottleneck? If not, you should do that before thinking about h264 or GPU stuff, as those won't help if they're not at the bottleneck.

Comment: How are you reading the pixels?  The 7-argument BufferedImage.getRGB is probably faster than the 2-argument BufferedImage.getRGB.  Directly accessing a DataBuffer is probably faster than either getRGB.

Comment: @Siguza It takes half the time to read the pixels and compare the image and half the time to compress it

Comment: @VGR I'll give it a go with DataBuffers when I get home and see if there is any significant improvement

Comment: 100ms to compress or compare an image? Hah, god knows that can go faster... what kind of compression are you using? And what kind of data structures?

Comment: `Gzip/IOStream`, and just a `BufferedImage` read from `Robot.createScreenCapture(...)`